# Downloding Email attachment in C

Tags: c, email, curl, download, libcurl

Im writing a function in C using libcurl(curl library) that downloads the attachment of the last email that has been sent to my outlook Email and returns the FILE pointer to the attachment and it uses POP3 protocol but when I compile and run the code libcurl gives me error saying "login denied" ; The problem is that the email address and password that im giving to the function is correct and the settings for allowing POP3 for my outlook email is turned on and there is no special security on my outlook email like two steps verification or even a phone number for receiving code but as I said the error says login denied !
Can somebody help me to solve this problem ? and for the record I think maybe the "sprintf" section and the URL part of it need some modification for downloading the attachment of the last email that has been sent to my Email !
if you could point out any problem with the function I'll be so glad :)

here is the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

FILE* downloadLastEmailAttachment(const char* username, const char* password) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    FILE *attachmentFile = fopen("attachment.dat", "wb"); // Open file to write attachment data
    if (!attachmentFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open attachment file for writing.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        char url[256];

        // Compose the Outlook email URL
        snprintf(url, sizeof(url), "pop3s://outlook.office365.com/INBOX/;UIDL");

        // Set curl options
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, username);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, password);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, attachmentFile);

        // Perform the request
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to download email: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            fclose(attachmentFile);
            attachmentFile = NULL;
        }

        // Clean up
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return attachmentFile;
}
```